# C++ class diagram Visual Studio 2022. I can't add a class to the mapping

Tags: c++, visual-studio, diagram

Once again, the God-fearing and beloved (no) program Vusial Studio is forcing me to ask for help! I have a problem with the class diagram in C++. I want to add a class to the display and....error

> "One or more of the selected elements cannot be added to the class diagram. This may be due to several limitations of the tool. Call for help for more information."

(by dragging and dropping from the Solution Explorer to the diagram)
I have no idea how to deal with it. Maybe it has something to do with adding the project to the version control system.

This is what the project schema looks like:
[image: d]

Tried adding a class to the diagram and waiting for it to display

Comment: May i know if your problem has been solved? Could you provide [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

According to the document: [Class Designer errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/additional-information-about-errors?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.classdesigner.CPlusPlusTypeCannotBeAdded)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022):

Class Designer does not track the location of your source files

> To resolve the error, drag the modified or relocated source code to
> the class diagram again to display it.

This problem also occurs in my new MFC app. I opened the class file to make some changes and save it. Then the class designer works fine.